# Does iOS ATS include ICE for WebRTC?

Tags: ios, webrtc, tls1.2

I use WebRTC on my iOS app, and I setup some STUN and TURN servers for WebRTC. Do I have to add these servers' domains to Allow Arbitrary Loads of ATS setting?

Comment: I can't confirm with 100% certainty, but I work on a webrtc-based ios app using ICE and I didn't add the domains. My app works as intended so at least in my case it's not necessary, it might be different for other servers.